# Array of structs not updating in C project

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently trying to make a Student Database system for my introductory C class. I am working on the feature of adding new students to the database so that it can be displayed. However, whenever i try to print out each individual feature of a struct in the array, it does not return what I intended. Floats become 0 and strings are not visible.

For context, here is the code used to display each element of the array

```
void displayStudents() {

  printf("\t\tList of Student Information\n");
  printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n ");
  printf("|No.| \t \t \t Name \t \t \t |\t Major \t\t| GPA |");
  printf("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");


  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < (currentEntries); i++) {
    printf("%s",listOfStudents[currentEntries].name);
    printf("%f",listOfStudents[currentEntries].gpa);
    printf("%s",listOfStudents[currentEntries].major);
    
    // these print statemnts above print "", 0, and "" respectively.

  }

  
}
```

Here are the functions used to add new students into the array

```
typedef struct Student {
  float gpa;
  char major[100];
  char name[100];

} student;


student createNewStudent(char sname[100], float gpa, char smajor[100]) {
  student newstudent;
  newstudent.gpa = gpa;
  strcpy(newstudent.name,sname);
  strcpy(newstudent.major,smajor);
  return newstudent;
}
```

```
void addNewStudents() {
  char name[100];
  char major[100];
  float gpa;

  if (currentEntries > 20) {
    currentEntries = 20;
    printf("Database is full");
    return;
  }
  printf("\t\t Insert Student Information \n");
  printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \n ");
  printf("Name: \t ");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
  printf("\nMajor\t: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",major);
  printf("\nGPA\t:");
  scanf(" %f", &gpa);

  listOfStudents[currentEntries] = createNewStudent(name,gpa,major);
  currentEntries++;  

}
```

and here is how theyre called in main()

```
  scanf("%d", &selection);
  switch(selection) {
      case 1:
        displayStudents();
        promptKeyPress(&inMenu);
        break;
      case 2:
        addNewStudents(); 
        promptKeyPress(&inMenu);
        break;

      default:

        programRunning = false;
        break;
```

also, both currentEntries and listOfStudents are defined as global variables

```
int currentEntries = 0;
student listOfStudents[20];
```

So, my question is, how should I tackle this problem so that the displayStudents function would print the correct values of my input (the student name, major and gpa)?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OT: `if (currentEntries > 20) {` is wrong. Remember arrays are numbered, for instance, 0 to 19 for 20 elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (currentEntries); i++) {
  printf("%s",listOfStudents[currentEntries].name);
  printf("%f",listOfStudents[currentEntries].gpa);
  printf("%s",listOfStudents[currentEntries].major);
    
  // these print statemnts above print "", 0, and "" respectively.

}
```

The index is wrong. Replace `currentEntries` inside the loop with `i`:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (currentEntries); i++) {
  printf("%s",listOfStudents[i].name);
  printf("%f",listOfStudents[i].gpa);
  printf("%s",listOfStudents[i].major);
    
  // these print statemnts above print "", 0, and "" respectively.

}
```

As well noted in the comments section, you should also fix the following block:

```
if (currentEntries > 20) {
  currentEntries = 20;
  printf("Database is full");
  return;
}
```

To something like:

```
if (currentEntries == 20) {
  printf("Database is full");
  return;
}
```

Comment: Cant believe i missed that! thanks for the answer.